# Poisson Exponential Distribution with slight change

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How would I derive the CDF of P(T$\ge$t). I know the CDF of an exponential poisson distribution is F(t) = P(T$\le$t) = 1-P(T$>$t) = 1-P(X=0) = 1-$e^{(-\lambda)(t)}$, but in the case of (T$\ge$t) we cannot choose X to be 0.

I tried solving it by reversing what was done in the original Exponential Poisson distribution and got F(t) = P(T$\ge$t) = 1-P(T$<$t). In this case I think we cannot choose X to be 0 because there must already be an arrival by the time we hit time t because of the inequality P(T$<$t).

Comment: If $T$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, there is no such thing as the cdf of $\Pr(X\ge t)$. We have $\Pr(X\ge t)=e^{-\lambda t}$.

Comment: Is Pr(X$\ge$t) the same as Pr(T$\ge$t)?

Comment: You have not defined $X$. I have a feeling you are conditioning on having waited an amount $X=0$. That does not help in the analysis of $T$.

Comment: The 1-P(T>t) = 1-P(X=0) is the probability that we observe the first arrival after time t is the same as the probability that we observe no arrivals from now until time t. Does that make more sense? I'm confused about this myself as well.

Comment: In my answer, I had called the waiting time random variable by the name $X$. To go along with your notation, it should have been $T$. And forget about conditioning on having waited time $0$. Whenever we start timing, the waiting time until the first event has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\Pr(T\ge t)=\Pr(T=t)+\Pr(T\gt t).\tag{1}$$

(i) Note that $\Pr(T\gt t)=1-\Pr(T\le t)=1-(1-e^{-\lambda t})=e^{-\lambda t}$.

(ii) Also, $\Pr(T=t)=0$. Indeed, if $Y$ is any random variable with continuous distribution, then for any real number $a$, we have $\Pr(Y=a)=0$.

Using Equation (1), and facts (i) and (ii), we get that $\Pr(T\ge t)=e^{-\lambda t}$.

**Another way:**
$$\Pr(T\ge t)=\int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=e^{-\lambda t}.$$

**Remark:** The fact that for a continuous random variable $Y$, we have $\Pr(Y=a)=0$, is useful. It means that we can casually replace $\lt$ by $\le$, or vice-versa, without affecting probabilities.